# Not registering a click from a manual mouseclick in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm working on a website and currently working on a scripts file for a page where an image is put on fullscreen mode. There is a toolbar in this mode where there is a div with the name of the piece and some buttons. I'm trying to register a click on the div with the name as an event(close fullscreen and open a link to that image), but i'm having issues from listeners (particularly a zoom feature on the image).

When I click on the div, the zoom effect from clicking on the image happens instead.

however, from the following snippet, I can get the "I am clickable" to show. I'm unsure what to look for or what to search, so if someone can lead me anywhere, I would appreciate.

The following snippet is written in document.ready

```
                jQuery('div#locationcontainer').click(function(event){
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    console.log("I am clickable");
                });

               jQuery('div#locationcontainer').trigger('click');
```

Manually clicking on the div does not register the event. I figure if it was bubbling up, all events would be registered, but that isn't the case. I'm somehow not clicking on the div I want (which is about 200px by 200px at least)

Answer (score 0):

Event Click jQuery

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('div#locationcontainer').click(function(event){
                    //event.stopPropagation();
                    //console.log("I am clickable");
                    alert('ok');
                });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="locationcontainer">
click event
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

hopefully can help